# Priority scheduling OS bash file

Tags: linux, bash, operating-system

I am trying to make bash file to calculate Waiting time and Average Waiting time for process with priority algorithm . I don't know what is wrong with it i keep says unexpected end near '}' line 39

```
    echo "Enter Number Of process"
read num
let id[$i]=$i+1
for((i=0;i<num;i++))
{
echo "Enter Burst Time For Process P$id[$i]"
read burst[$i]
}

for((i=0;i<num;i++))
{
echo "Enter Priority Time For Process P$id[$i]"
read priority[$i]
}

waiting[0]=0

for((i=0;i<num;i++))
{
for((j=0;j<num;j++))
{
if [ ${priority[$i]} > ${priority[$j]} ]
then
temp2=${priority[$i]}
priority[$i]=${priority[$j]}
priority[$j]=$temp2
temp=${arrival[$j]}
arrival[$i]=${arrival[$j]}
arrival[$j]=$temp
temp1=${burst[$i]}
burst[$i]=${burst[$j]}
burst[$j]=$temp1

}
let tot={burst[$i]}+$tot
echo "arrival[$i] priority[$i] burst[$i] $tot"
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Indenting your code properly helps you find syntax and logic errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last `for` and `if` are missing their end statements. Insert `fi` and `}` near the end of your script.
Then try [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for the remaining errors.